# I made a confetti in my app but all other buttons and switches stopped working?

Tags: ios, swift

As the code shows, I have the switch which starts the animation when turned on, but the confetti anyway is displayed and doesn't let me have button interactions !

```
@IBAction func `switch`(_ sender: UISwitch) {

    if(sender.isOn==true){
        senderText.text="YAYA!"
        supportText.text="we have added a reminder for you"
        supportIcon.isHidden=false
        support2.isHidden=true
        confettiView.startConfetti()
    }
    else{
        senderText.text="OKAY"
        supportText.text="you wont be disturbed"
        supportIcon.isHidden=true
        support2.isHidden=false
    }

}



var confettiView: SAConfettiView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    confettiView = SAConfettiView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    confettiView.colors = [UIColor(red:0.95, green:0.40, blue:0.27, alpha:1.0),
                           UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.78, blue:0.36, alpha:1.0),
                           UIColor(red:0.48, green:0.78, blue:0.64, alpha:1.0),
                           UIColor(red:0.30, green:0.76, blue:0.85, alpha:1.0),
                           UIColor(red:0.58, green:0.39, blue:0.55, alpha:1.0)]

    confettiView.intensity = 0.5
    confettiView.type = .Diamond
    confettiView.type = .Confetti
    view.addSubview(confettiView)
```

Comment: keep in mind about the view hierarchy ..... bring all buttons to front ...

Comment: `confettiView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that your confettiView is on top of all the other views and is receiving all the touches, preventing buttons and switches to receive them

```
confettiView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

This line of code to be inserted right after your confettiView initialization should solve the issue, as the confetti view will no longer intercept all touches.

Another solution (depending on your design requirements) would be to bring all the buttons to front, if you have a reference for them, or to remove the confetti view if you want an animation of defined duration.

Also please not that

```
confettiView.type = .Diamond
confettiView.type = .Confetti
```

will cause the type to be .Confetti. Consider to remove one of the two type assign statement. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `confettiView` is above all of your other `UIView`'s and `UIButton`'s.

`confettiView = SAConfettiView(frame: self.view.bounds)` makes your `confettiView` the size of the entire screen. You're then adding it to the `view` with `view.addSubview(confettiView)`. Remove the `confettiView` after your animation.

For example:

```
confettiView.removeFromSuperview()
```